# Time and temperature axes that are sorted by plot function in matab

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, temperature

I have an acquisition by a ph-meter, divided into 3 days. I have extracted the time in `hh:mm:ss` format for each day. It means that first day is from `12:32` to `14:39`, second from `14:12` to `16:17` etc. Same for the temperature (from 23 to 24°, 2 day from 22 to 24 etc).

Now I have to plot the data (`ph` `wrt` `T` and `Time`), but if I concatenate the 3 time and `T` vectors, or create a single column vector for each time and temperature, MATLAB automatically sorts in increasing values the values of the `x`-axis of the plot. I need to preserve the original values along the axes (it means that values have to be `14:32` `14:33` `14:34` `12:24` `12:25` and so on, same for temperature) because i have to preserve the continuity of the data along the time of acquisition.

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Convert your hh:mm:ss to datenum -- probably need to add day, month,year so it is in the correct order you want it. Then you can just set your tick to be HH:MM:SS or seconds or whatever you need. 
Look here:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetick.html

Answer (score 0):

From 2014b you can use [`datetime`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html).

Choose either the actual dates of recording, or some arbitrary dates which are one day apart, and assign the date part to your data like

```
% Create 3 random time arrays of the format 'hh:mm:ss'
t = [randi([10,14], 10,1), randi([0,59], 10,1), randi([0,59], 10,1)];
T1 = [num2str(t(:,1), '%02i'), repmat(':', 10, 1), num2str(t(:,2), '%02i'),repmat(':', 10, 1), num2str(t(:,3), '%02i')];
t = [randi([10,14], 10,1), randi([0,59], 10,1), randi([0,59], 10,1)];
T2 = [num2str(t(:,1), '%02i'), repmat(':', 10, 1), num2str(t(:,2), '%02i'),repmat(':', 10, 1), num2str(t(:,3), '%02i')];
t = [randi([10,14], 10,1), randi([0,59], 10,1), randi([0,59], 10,1)];
T3 = [num2str(t(:,1), '%02i'), repmat(':', 10, 1), num2str(t(:,2), '%02i'),repmat(':', 10, 1), num2str(t(:,3), '%02i')];

% Convert to dates on consecutive days
D1 = datetime(strcat('2000-01-01-', T1), 'inputformat', 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss');
D2 = datetime(strcat('2000-01-02-', T1), 'inputformat', 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss');
D3 = datetime(strcat('2000-01-03-', T1), 'inputformat', 'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss');

% Plot
data = rand(30,1);
plot([D1, D2, D3], data);
```